# Is exposing your form validation requirements via a Javascript regex a security issue?

Tags: javascript, regex, bots

On our website, I've added a sign up form for new users with server side validation implemented. I mentioned to my team during stand up that I was going to implement some client side validation as well, so that the page could be responsive to a user's input so that a user would know some of the input requirements as they are typing instead of having to hit submit to know if anything is incorrect with their input. (all server side validation will remain.)

My team lead was okay with validation on all inputs except password. His specific concern was that having a regex in JavaScript is a security issue because it could potentially be sniffed by a bot. The bot could grab our regex and thus know our password requirements. It could then proceed to try to compromise a user's account by spam/brute force guess a user's password - having an easier time of it because the bot now knows the password requirements.

Is exposing your validation requirements via regex a serious security issue?

More specifically, is it a security issue regarding bots that sniff for regex?

I'd like to add that in our case, we have some basic measures in place to protect ourselves, such as locking a user's account after so many login attempts.

Comment: If someone wanted to know your password requirements, couldn't they just go to the account signup page and see the requirements?

Comment: It's an "issue" in that it might make your security slightly worse. But it's on the level of having 10000 or 10001 grains of rice for dinner. One is technically more food, but it's not going to make any difference either way as to how full you feel.

Comment: It seems to me this is a theoretical security issue (except when you have very strict password requirements, for example 5 digits, no more, no less, that can be brute-forced very fast). But if your team lead has problems with it, just do what he wants, it's not something worth making a big problem of.

Comment: If your password requirements are so strict that this matters, they are wrong  in the first place. This should never be a problem. It'd be very frustrating to the user trying to guess the password requirements instead of seeing then, for absolutely no measurable security gain.

Comment: If your requirements are "at least 8 characters, allows letters, numbers, symbols" (about 80 characters), and you rate limit to 1 failed login attempt per second, it should take an attacker with all this knowledge around 53 million years to guess a randomly-chosen password. Your practical weak point is users choosing bad passwords, not attackers brute-forcing them because they know the backend logic.

Comment: @Luan Nico & Andrew Rueckert I was making a theoretical point, I was not promoting strict password requirements.

Answer (score 1):

No this wouldn't be an issue. It would be no different than listing the password requirements on the sign up page.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing your validation in javascript is not a risk.

Relying on client side validation is a security risk.

If your team lead's objection is what you have described here, then he/she should not be leading a software development team.